# Is there a way to determine if an R program was run from the command line?

Tags: r

I'd like the flow of control to vary depending on where an R program is called from. Something like

```
if (called_from == 'GUI') {
print('Hello GUI')} else {
print('Hello command line')
}
```

Is this possible? If so, please provide as many details as possible.

Comment: You can use `interactive()`. If TRUE the code is probably being run in a GUI, if FALSE, it's probably being run at the command line. See the `?interactive` help page for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (interactive()) {
  print('Hello GUI')
} else {
  print('Hello command line')
}
```